# How to create Sencha touch application using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sencha-touch-2

I use visual studio from couple of year. And now I am beginner to Sencha touch so please help me how can i create sencha touch app in visual studio.
Thanks for all.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha touch needs only a text editor and the command line tool provided from sencha.
Since the project its self is only a collection of css/html/js files you can just create the project via [command line](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command_app_touch) and use Visual Studio as text editor.
If you are building a web application with server side logic and you want to use sencha touch as frontend, you can just navigate with command line inside the public web directory and create the project with sencha cmd. Then use vs for code editing.
I did the same work with eclipse the only problem is that there are so many files and if u use an automatic build and js check it takes a lot of time to check the whole project.

Finally, if you are using only sencha touch and you dont need to do server stuff just use a text editor, I use Sublime Text 2, give it a try.

Comment: Thinks for replay.I want to use VS as text editor and debug java-script code. But when I try to create project using Sencha Cmd it gives me Error " package was not successful for unknown reason sencha creation " I have install sencha touch 4.0.4.84 I have tried  too much. help me if U can thanks

Comment: I think you are using sencha touch 2.3.1 and command line 4.0.4.x , anyway probably its a path or permissions issue. you have to use this:
sencha -sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-2-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/www/myapp
Pay attention to the sdk path and be sure to have the right permissions.

Comment: I new to sencha touch that will be easy but i am stuck here.I have two files 1.SenchaCmd-4.0.4.84-windows.exe which i have installed on my machine and 2.sencha-touch-2.3.1a-gpl which i don't know what to do with it. I open cmd and type cd C:\Users\Abdul Mutlib\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.4.84> sencha generate app myapp../myapp.and got error. Sorry I can't get sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-2-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/www/myapp. thanks for your time.

Comment: YOu alredy installed the command line tool, this means that you can use sencha commands, like generate build and so on.
The sdk is a zip file which you have to unzip and put in a directory like C:/sencha  When you do this you can create your app.
First navigate with command line into the folder where you want to create your project

Comment: Execute now 'sencha -sdk C:\sencha generate app MyApp /'
Which tells to sencha to create your app with MyApp name inside the current directory ( / )
you have to execute

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sencha Touch in Visual Studio 2015, with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova. I have written a post on how to integrate these three, and it might help you. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ea0e0/creating-a-new-cordova-mobile-application-using-sencha-touch/

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.

Comment: For that I would have to write the whole article in the Answer, you do see that the question is not about solving any specific problem but the user is asking for a tutorial. I don't see the point of your downvote in this specific case